# scheduled task shutdown on XP

Tags: windows-xp, shutdown, windows-task-scheduler

I'm attempting to use a scheduled task to shut down my win XP PC. I get the error: Task Scheduler Error 0x80070005: Access is denied. I'm logged in with administrative privileges but am unsure why the task isn't starting or won't work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone give me some pointers please?

Incidentally, as a work around, I have managed to get around this whole thing with a batch file on a timer.

Comment: Have you tried using Task Scheduler to start the batch file? i.e. if your batch file shuts down the PC, then let TS run the batch file at a certain time. Let TS use the highest privileges too.

Comment: I've just tried as a test, but it's the same as before. "0x80070005: Access is denied. You do not have permission to perform the requested task"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I have just tried this myself, and it has worked. So just checking if you have the correct settings, here is a screenshot of my settings. **Note:** I am using Windows Vista, but shouldn't make any difference.

*General Tab:*
[image: Task Schedule [General]]

Your batch file (for Windows XP) will only need the following line of code:

> shutdown.exe -s -t 00

Comment: There is no Need to write a Batch file, you can call shutdown.exe directly with the Parameters.

Comment: That works fine. The trick was to tick the "run only when user is logged on" box. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Oh ok, I was just going on with what was asked in the question. "I have managed to get around this whole thing with a batch file on a timer"